# Run function in background in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel-artisan, laravel-4.2

I have one function which take long time to execute so i want to run this function in background can it's possible?

I want to run this function on user click on button.
and don't want to run any command from terminal.

Thanks

Comment: you are looking for queue system. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues , it can help you with timeout flag option, for this you will need supervisor too.

Comment: YEs but run queue using code is possible?

Comment: you can run any sort of code using queues in laravel, its basically for backgrund jobs/task.

Comment: can you give example if possible?

Comment: ok wait for few mins.  I will post some example here.

Answer (score 1):

For implementing queue system these steps needs to be followed.

-- on button click route (/usertask/performAction)
In your controller suppose (UserTaskController.php) 
1- add namespace for your jobs.

```
<?php
use App\Jobs\ProcessTask; // job class that will be created later


class UserTaskController extends Controller
{


// controllers function
function performAction()
{
    ...
    ...
    ...

    // code to place background task
    $data =  [];
    $job  = ( new ProcessTask($userId, $data))->onQueue('ProcessTask');

    if ($this->dispatch($job)) {
        info('job dispatched');
    } else {
        info('job dispatch failed');
    }
    // code to place background task ends
}
```

now create a job file. (ProcessTask.php) inside your jobs folder.
ProcessTask.php

```
--------

<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Log;
use App\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ProcessTask extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{

    use InteractsWithQueue,
        SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    protected $userId;
    protected $data;


    public function __construct($userId, $data)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the command.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        try {
            // perform your task
            /*
            $this->userId
            $this->data
            */
            return true;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('ProcessTask:: Exception occured ');
            Log::error($e);
            $this->release(); //release the job back to queue, as attempts increase fail to be
            return false;
        }
    }


    public function failed()
    {
        Log::info('ProcessTask :: failed ends');
    }
}

?>
```

/// now you can run your jobs in terminal ()

```
php arrtisan queue:listen --queue=ProcessTask --timeout=600
```

in your terminal(or you can place this in supervisor)

settings related to queue driver--

```
/var/www/html/infinito/config/queue.php

make QUEUE_DRIVER as database.

'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'database'),
```

Comment: it's return 'Class 'App\Jobs\ProcessTask' not found' my laravel version in 4.2 it's familar with it?

Comment: create your jobs (processTask.php) file in app\Jobs folder